# Run custom admin command from view

Tags: django

I have a custom admin command that emails out reports. It normally runs from a cron job. What I would like to do is add a button to my web app that when clicked will cause the the admin command to run there and then rather than wait for the cron job to call it. How do I do this? Do I have to call out to a command line such as

```
python manage.py myadmincmd
```

or can I invoke the code from within a view? It seems it would be cleaner if I could do this from within a view without needing to break out to the command line.

Comment: As Daniel says you can use `call_command` or structure your code so that both the management command and the view call some third function that actually does the mail sending.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I call a custom Django manage.py command directly from a test driver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907506/how-can-i-call-a-custom-django-manage-py-command-directly-from-a-test-driver)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use `call_command`:

```
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('myadmincmd')
```

Comment: can we get the cron response on web-page as it comes to console while processing command

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can we call command running background?