# Giving a web interface to a cli python script

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, web-applications, cgi

I have a python cli script that asks for a series of different inputs, processes them and prints an output for every input, maintaining a state. Es:

form:Type your name

user: myname

script: your name is myname and it has 6 letters

form: Type your surname:

user: mysurname

script: your surname is mysurname and it has..

script: you are myname mysurname

I'd like to give it a web interface.
I know how to use AJAX and CGI to get one single input and print one single output in a web page.

Is there a more elegant way to do it without splitting my script in several parts and recording its state inside a file?

Comment: If you're using python and familiar with it I think you would easily be able to set up django as server side and then use a basic html file with some javascript to make an AJAX request to your python script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run my python script from within a web browser and process the results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959936/how-can-i-run-my-python-script-from-within-a-web-browser-and-process-the-results)