# How to run management command from django view.py

Tags: python, django

I want to run my custom command from django view which create new user. Here is my command

```
python manage.py  tenant_command createsuperuser --schema=schema_name
```

Here schema name my be change

Above command is same as

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Here i didn't know how to pass username, email and password and confirm password any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run custom admin command from view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250970/run-custom-admin-command-from-view)

Comment: up-to some level but i also need to pass username, email, and password, here I'm using custom user model extends from abstract base user

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244382/how-to-automate-createsuperuser-on-django

Comment: Why use a management command? Just create the User using the [User API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#creating-users)

Comment: Yeah you are right, that was my mistake

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to achieve what you trying to do:

- Using code to change the user object and save it to database
- Calling the command you mentioned

According to [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code) you can call your commands in code using `call_command` function, it takes arguments and pass them to command too:

```
call_command("custom_command", arguments..)
```

In the other way you have access to User model in your view so you can import it directly and create the user:

```py
from django.contrib.auth impor get_user_model

get_user_model().objects.create()
```

Comment: Thanks for you helps, Here I'm using different schema for different tenants, somethings like isolated schema, Anyway I've solved my issue