# Test case Django command PyCharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm, testcase

I'm a new Pycharm's user, and in my project I created a Django command that needs two parameters. I know that to run it correctly I must add additional options and it works fine.

Now i would like create a test case for it, but i don't know how add additional option in test case.

I should add in Run Configuration or directly in test case? and how?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to put all of the command logic into a separate function that can be tested independently. Then the command simply calls that function.

If that's not feasible for some reason you can test a command directly with

```
from django.core.management import call_command

call_command('my_command', 'foo', bar='baz')
```

as outlined here:
[How can I call a custom Django manage.py command directly from a test driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907506/how-can-i-call-a-custom-django-manage-py-command-directly-from-a-test-driver)