# Django ORM reset AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: django-views, django-orm

Universal SQL analog for ORM

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

Model TestData

```
TestData.objects.all().delete()
```

id = [1 .. 53]

import data from csv_file

id = [54 ... ]

del data ...

Django Main functional for reset work fine

```
python manage.py sqlsequencereset test_app
```

or code run command (work)

```
from django.core import management
management.call_command('sqlsequencereset')
```

Is it possible to reset AUTO_INCREMENT with Django **ORM**, without  management call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I call a custom Django manage.py command directly from a test driver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907506/how-can-i-call-a-custom-django-manage-py-command-directly-from-a-test-driver)

Comment: manage.py work fine. Analog ALTER TABLE `my_name` AUTO_INCREMENT =1;