# DJANGO: How to get App URLS Inside a Function?

Tags: django, django-extensions

I want to get Django Site URL's inside another function.

I know and i am using, [django_extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Currently am fetching using, `./manage.py show_urls`

but i want fetch URLs into variable.

is there a way to use `django-extensions` inside a custom function?

Try 1:

```
from django.core.management import call_command
```

this also not helpful. seems work only with Preinstalled Modules

Comment: Can you elaborate more on that question? Maybe provide some code example and desired behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I call a custom Django manage.py command directly from a test driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907506/how-can-i-call-a-custom-django-manage-py-command-directly-from-a-test-driver)

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? I suspect a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)...