# How can I call a custom Django manage.py command directly from code with specific database connection

Tags: django, command, multiple-databases

I followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907506/how-can-i-call-a-custom-django-manage-py-command-directly-from-a-test-driver) to run customer Django command programmatically, but it is limited for just one database connection.

I have Django app configured with multiple database , is it possible to run custom Django command using specific database connection?

exactly like when we use `connections["DB_NAME_CONNECTION"].cursor()` to execute an sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a new settings module ([here's a guide](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2017/07/03/django-tip-20-working-with-multiple-settings-modules.html)) that contains your specific database connection configuration, and then use that settings module when using `call_command()`:

```py
management.call_command('mycommand', '--settings=mysite.settings.specificconnection')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! that is the answer i need !